# How to know quantity of users with turned off images in browser?

Tags: image, browser

I'm working on the quite popular website, which looks good if user has turned on "Load images" option in his browser's settings.

When you try to open the website with "turned off images" option, it becomes not usable, many components won't work, because user won't see "important" buttons(we don't use standard OS buttons).

So, we can't understand and measure negative business impact of this mistake(absent alt/title attributes).
We can't set priority for this task - because we don't know how much such users comes to our website.

Please give me some advice how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the logs for how many hits you get on a page without the subsequent requests from the browser for the other images.

Of course the browser might have images cached, so look for the *first time* you get a hit.

You can even use IP address for this, since it's OK if you throw out good data (that is, hits that are new that you disregard).  The question is just: Of the hits you *know* are first-time, how many don't get images?

If this is a public page (i.e. not a web application that you've logged in to), also disregard search engine bots to the greatest extent possible; they usually won't retrieve images.